# ¿como utilizar otro objeto dentro del data() en una función que está dentro de un objeto dentro del mismo data() en un componente vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, funciones

tengo un problema que no eh podido resolver en ya tres días, resulta que hice un componente que renderiza un arreglo de botones:

```
        <button v-if="button.type == 'simple'"  @click="button.action" type="button" class="btn mr-2" :class="button.class" v-html="button.label"></button>
```

el ejemplo del objeto que renderiza es el siguiente:

```
{
data(){
    return{
        buttons:[
            {
                type: "simple",
                class: "btn-primary",
                label: "Nueva proiedad  <i class='ml-1 fas fa-plus-square'></i>",
                action: (ids)=>{
                    this.$store.dispatch('property/delete', ids);
                },
              },
        ],
        ids:[]
    }
}
```

}

en action tengo una función y quisiera mandar el array ids por medio de la función para mandarlo al store de bla pero si le hago un console.log a ids me sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me parece que es el action del click, muchas gracias por su ayuda les agradezco su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que debería llevar dentro el parámetro `ids`?

Comment: Hola solo son números serían ids que inserto por medio de otra función ejemp: [12,45,67]

Comment: ¿Y cómo se lo insertas con otra función? Porque veo que estás llamando a la función `action` en el `@click` pero no le estás pasando ningún argumento. Tal y como tienes tu código ahora no veo que le estés dando un valor al parámetro `ids`.

Comment: Esos ids los estoy insertando dentro de otro componente... se llama table, en cada fila tiene un  checkbox, al momento de seleccionar hace un  @click e inserta los por medio de un emit a ese campo de ids

Comment: Creo que deberías pasarnos el código de ese componente también, porque si no nos falta información para poder ayudarte y no tenemos un contexto completo de tu problema. Para agregar ese código puedes editar tu pregunta e incluirlo.